# Find pattern with RegEx and replace

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the following two scenarios, where i need to replace either a `href=".."` value or `src=".."` value.

The pattern is

- `<img src="/~/media/75F8BA07F3BC4C3F91A71D6A049E6BD4.ashx" alt="" />`
- `<a href="/~/link.aspx?_id=2CD5F3FBD0334A7DA7CB81F9520BEED5&amp;_z=z">Some text</a>`

The GUID is always 32 charaters long, and when found, I need to replace the entire href og src tag, of the element, with a new value.

Any ideas as to how this can be done?

Comment: Could you show how the string should look like after the replacement?

Comment: @Gurman ofcourse.

Before: <img src="/~/media/75F8BA07F3BC4C3F91A71D6A049E6BD4.ashx" alt="" />
After: <img src="/media/myfolder/myimage.png" alt="" />

Before: <a href="/~/link.aspx?_id=2CD5F3FBD0334A7DA7CB81F9520BEED5&amp;_z=z">Some text</a>
After: <a data-udi="umb://document/fd9383ca72234b8e8465c257f2d60f66" href="/{localLink:umb://document/fd9383ca72234b8e8465c257f2d60f66}">Some text</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pattern you need:

```
(src="(\/~\/media\/([A-Z0-9]{32})\.ashx)")|(href="(\/~\/link\.aspx\?_id=([A-Z0-9]{32})&amp;_z=z"))
```

Have a look at [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/RvaOzg/3)

Comment: But that takes everything inside every src and href tags, right? That i dont need - it is ONLY the src and HREF tags that matches my pattern (ie. contains the 32 charetercs GUID). There are also other src and href values, which do not contain the GUID, and therefore should not be replaced.

Comment: How do you know the path in the image tag will always be the same?

Comment: @brother I edited my answer and demo please have a look

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Thank you. How can i extract the GUID from that? I need the GUID to lookup in an array, to see what i need to replace the value with?

Comment: I edited my answer and demo, just put GUID between parantheses and GROUP3 will be the GUID

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for replacing the image tags as you described:

```
string input = "<img src="/~/media/75F8BA07F3BC4C3F91A71D6A049E6BD4.ashx" alt="" />";
input = Regex.Replace(input,
                      @"<img [^>]*src=""/~/([^/]+)/[A-Z0-9]{32}[^""]*""[^>]*/>",
                      "<img src=\"/$1/myfolder/myimage.png\" alt=\"\" />");
```

I would do a separate replacement on the anchor tags, and I will leave this to you as a follow up exercise.

By the way, it is in general bad practice to manipulate HTML using regular expressions, so you might want to move away from this if possible.